# SQL max() with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, greatest-n-per-group

Would like ask you for a little help

Have `Sql query` where i list all orders, but there i need add last `OrderStatus` throught `OrderStatusID`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.OrderNr, 
    a.CompanyName, 
    max(a.OrderStatusID) AS 'xxx'

FROM [NB].[dbo].[Npos] as a
INNER JOIN [NB].[dbo].[Npos_Order_Status_Name] as b 
ON 
a.OrderStatusID = b.OrderStatusID

GROUP BY  OrderNr, CompanyName
```

in `[NB].[dbo].[Npos_Order_Status_Name]` are

```
OrderStatusID | OrderStatusName
--------------------------------
            0 | Start
            1 | Stop
            2 | Pause
```

I tried it with `inner join` but i make something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT. The GROUP BY returns no duplicate rows.

Comment: You need the highest `a.OrderStatusID` for a given `OrderNr` and `CompanyName`? Or overall?

Comment: For each OrderNr-ComanyName -> latest OrderStatusName

Comment: Also, what is "wrong"? What is the desired output compared to the one which you are getting?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this query will do what you want

```
SELECT t.OrderNr, t.CompanyName, b.OrderStatusName
FROM
(
   SELECT 
    OrderNr, 
    CompanyName, 
    max(OrderStatusID) AS 'maxOrderStatus'
  FROM [NB].[dbo].[Npos]
  GROUP BY  OrderNr, CompanyName
) t
JOIN [NB].[dbo].[Npos_Order_Status_Name] as b 
  ON  t.maxOrderStatus = b.OrderStatusID
```

or using window functions

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(     
    SELECT
        a.*,
        row_number() over (partition by OrderNr, CompanyName order by OrderStatusID desc) rn
    FROM [NB].[dbo].[Npos] as a
    INNER JOIN [NB].[dbo].[Npos_Order_Status_Name] as b 
      ON a.OrderStatusID = b.OrderStatusID
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

However, from my experience, the second variant can be slightly slower in certain cases.